# 2sxc dnn sql database and DNN search

Tags: 2sxc

If got this code in my razor template:

```
@using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules
@using ToSic.Eav.DataSources
@using ToSic.SexyContent.Search
@functions
{
// Customize data not used - but it could often be used in search-demos, so I left it in
public override void CustomizeData()
{
    // Don't customize anything, nothing to customize in this case
}

/// <summary>
/// Populate the search - ensure that each entity has an own url/page
/// </summary>
/// <param name="searchInfos"></param>
/// <param name="moduleInfo"></param>
/// <param name="startDate"></param>
public override void CustomizeSearch(Dictionary<string, List<ISearchInfo>> searchInfos, ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime startDate)
{
    // all we'll do is tell the search engine that the URL is a bit different for each found entity
    foreach (var si in searchInfos["SearchIndex"])
    {
        si.QueryString = "?id=" + si.Entity.EntityId;
    }
}
}
```

With this data queries:

[image: data query]

But the dnn search is not picking up the items? I'm not seeing errors in the dnn logs when the search indexer runs. Do i have to use the Customize data function?

the query i run is this one:

```
SELECT [Hotel_ID]  as EntityId
  ,[Hotel_ID]
  ,[Hotel_Name] + ' in ' + [City_Name] as EntityTitle
  ,[Hotel_Name]
  ,[Hotel_Address1]
  ,[Hotel_Address2]
  ,[Hotel_Address3]
  ,[Hotel_LAT]
  ,[Hotel_LNG]
  ,[Hotel_Website]
  ,[Hotel_Telephone1]
  ,[Hotel_Telephone2]
  ,[Hotel_Email1]
  ,[Hotel_Email2]
  ,[Hotel_Fax1]
  ,[Hotel_Logo]
  ,[Hotel_ZoomLevel]
  ,[City_Name]
  ,[Neighborhood_Name]
  ,[Departments_Name]
  FROM [CI-HotelList]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think you'll need the CustomizeData in this case - it was meant primarily for the times before visual query was possible. 

That said - I think you're already doing the right things. Did you verify all the basics (indexer is running, module is visible to users etc.?)

Comment: Ok, i think i found something has it something to do that i use 2 templates? http://www.mvanlaar.net/portals/0/2sxc-dnn-search2.png. Because the search demo who uses 1 template works.

Comment: Ok, thats the problem. remodeld the search integration eample to do what i want.